# Django select query with limited fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to select a object with just one return field. I can do it using values. But the problem is when not using values it returns an object and when using values it returns a dictionary. Any reason for this difference. And is there a way I can get a return of objects with just one or two fields.

```
     obj=UserProfile.objects.get(pk=1)
     obj=UserProfile.objects.values('my_field').get(pk=1)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [only()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) method and  enter fields which you need

```
obj=UserProfile.objects.only('my_field').get(pk=1)
```

Comment: Tx, can I also get foreign key reference using only() ? such as my_field2.another_field